# Could someone explain how SSL helps me on an e-commerce website?

Tags: php, security, ssl

I'm making a small e-commerce website where users can purchase items from a shopping card. The items are just some printings and price range is between 50 usd to 300 usd.

Many people suggests using SSL. I know that it encrypts the data transfer between browser and server using a secure socket, but I have never used it before.

How exactly does it help me secure my website? Would it automatically prevent any possibilities of SQL Injections or XSS exploits on my website ?

Ps. I've searched before making this topic. A short reply or a guide for a beginner like me will be appreciated!

Comment: SSL basically gives client and server a private (almost) soundproof room to talk to each other on. What they talk about, however, is anybody's guess. SSL is almost a necessitous task for an application like this, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prevents people from eavesdropping on your guests connections. That way, when you put in login or credit card information, people in the middle of the connection cannot easily read it.

Comment: "easily"? (Also, as with anything, the security depends on quite a few conditions.)

Comment: Who can be in the middle of connection? ISP? Data center? Or even an application which reads ongoing packets in operating system? Or all of them?

Comment: @ChrisOlsson All of them.

Comment: @ChrisOlsson Both, but also think in terms of the real world. If i'm at a coffee shop, anyone on the same network could view my connection. There are many people that have access to traffic. SSL is hugely necessary for ecommerce.

Comment: Yup, I see now. By the way, when I install SSL on my server, is there any configurations should be done in Apache, or should I change my PHP scripts to support it? Or is it just install-forget?

Comment: @ChrisOlsson Buy an SSL Cert, then configure it with Apache and you should be set. Don't forget to accept either mine or the other users answer, since I see this is your first question.

Comment: There is much more to SSL than that. Don't forget the role of the CAs.

Comment: @fge I wanted to keep it as simple as possible as the OP requested.

Comment: @JonSheppard It required 15 minutes before I can accept an answer. I just accepted this one. Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 3):

> [...]there is a SQL Injection or XSS exploits on my website. Does it automatically prevent such exploits?

The answer to this is "no".

SSL means "Secure *Sockets* Layer" and it does its best effort ensuring precisely that: securing communications at the network level, by preventing eavesdropping as much as possible. SSL has no knowledge of HTTP(S).

Notwithstanding any attacks targeting SSL itself which are out of the scope of this question, the main things to remember are these:

- it secures any communication to the server, whether the client is malicious or not;
- it provides no control over what the client "does to" the server once the connection is established.